# Heavy stateful UDF in pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, user-defined-functions

I have to run a really heavy python function as UDF in Spark and I want to cache some data inside UDF. The case is similar to one mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49515211/pyspark-cache-in-udf)

I am aware that it is slow and wrong.
But the existing infrastructure is in spark and I don't want set up a new infrastructure and deal with data loading/parallelization/fail safety separately for this case.

This is how my spark program looks like:

```
from mymodule import my_function # here is my function
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf
from pyspark.sql.session import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()

schema = StructType().add("input", "string")
df = spark.read.format("json").schema(schema).load("s3://input_path")

udf1 = udf(my_function, StructType().add("output", "string"))
df.withColumn("result", udf1(df.input)).write.json("s3://output_path/")
```

The `my_function` internally calls a method of an object with a slow constructor.
Therefore I don't want the object to be initialized for every entry and I am trying to cache it:

```
from my_slow_class import SlowClass
from cachetools import cached

@cached(cache={}) 
def get_cached_object():
    # this call is really slow therefore I am trying 
    # to cache it with cachetools
    return SlowClass() 

def my_function(input):
    slow_object = get_cached_object()
    output = slow_object.call(input)
    return {'output': output}
```

`mymodule` and `my_slow_class` are installed as modules on each spark machine.

It seems working. The constructor is called only a few times (only 10-20 times for 100k lines in input dataframe). And that is what I want.

My concern is multithreading/multiprocessing inside Spark executors and if the  cached `SlowObject` instance is shared between many parallel `my_function` calls.

Can I rely on the fact that `my_function` is called once at a time inside python processes on worker nodes? Does spark use any multiprocessing/multithreading in python process that executes my UDF?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spark forks Python process to create individual workers, however all processing in the individual worker process is sequential, unless multithreading or multiprocessing is used explicitly by the `UserDefinedFunction`.

So as long as state is used for caching and `slow_object.call` is a pure function  you have nothing to worry about.